# Possible to convert the clipboard to text and copy it to another computer?

Tags: windows, clipboard

Is it possible to convert the contents of the clipboard to text (such like BASE64) copy it to another computer and import this text to have the contents of the original clipboard on the other computer?

Something like a clipboard manager?

The contents of the clipboard is anything but text, e.g. a selection of a picture.

Should work on Windows 7 and 8.1 x64.

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of the Windows RDP Client offer clipboard transfer functionality, (huge items can take a while,) but generally speaking you can copy and paste almost anything from the local system to the remote host over RDP these days. It is bidirectional as well, if you copy something in the remote machine you can pull it locally. The service basically syncs the systems so they have one common clipboard.

Many other remote access solutions offer the ability to send the clipboard contents back and forth as well. Most VNC solutions, things like LogMeIn, GoToAssist, Team Viewer, etc.